# WebPage is not getting loaded using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me with the below issue.

I have launched a URL using Selenium, got logged in and performed few actions. Next, I have clicked on a button then I should be navigated to another page. Unfortunately, the page is not getting loaded i.e., an empty webpage got loaded. The same happens in both Chrome and FireFox as well.

When I did the same manually, it works fine. Not sure what exactly the issue is. Please assist.
Thanks.